# Which files to remove from VCS in C++ project in Clion?

Tags: c++, git, github, clion

I am new to C++, and am running CLion with github.

I have the basic hello world project set up, and there are several .xml files in a `/.idea` folder that I am not sure I should be including. Right now, I am including everything.  My question is: what can I leave out of vcs?

Here is a snapshot of what I have (the .xmls are at the bottom; right now everything has been added to VCS, so they are all green):

[image]

The specific question is:

If I do not add the .xml files to version control, and I checkout the code from some other computer, will I be able to run the code? Or are some of the .xml files needed?

(didn't realize this was too broad.  will delete if it is still too broad).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can omit the entire .idea folder by creating a .gitignore file in the root directory and adding a line for

```
.idea
```

then you can select the .idea folder and under 'vcs' or 'git' choose 'revert' to remove them from staging if you have not committed them or to undo the commits that added them to the repo

good luck!

Comment: ok, awesome, worked--thanks.  just didn't want to break anything.  I'll be on a remote comp on monday.

Comment: @bordeo, All of those files are IDE files. You can create a project from source control on the other computer, even without CLion.

Comment: But what if we should not edit `.gitignore` file, or if folder `.idea` is part of project? I use CLion and I have issue with this "trash directories" created inside of project folder